# Creating a PHP form to submit an email message with Angular website

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, forms, http-status-code-404

I am currently trying to create a simple contact form that sends email using a PHP script. When the submit button in the form is clicked I call the function below in a controller. I get a 404 error with the post request. When I do a get request it works, but post returns 404.

Is this the correct way to post to a php form to send to an email in angular? Is there another method of doing this? Thanks!

```
$scope.url = 'feedback.php';
$scope.update = function(new_message){
    $http.post($scope.url, new_message).success(function (data, status) {
           if (data.success) {
                 $window.alert("Thank you! Your message has been sent.");
            }      
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            $window.alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
        });
  }
```

PHP code below:

```
<?php
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;

  $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
        mail("emailredacted@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);

        header("Location: http://localhost:3000/#/about");
?>
```

Form below:

```
<form class="col s12" id="email-form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input id="name" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="user.name">
          <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
          <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" ng-model="user.email">
          <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Email</label>
        </div><br><br><br>
         <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">message</i>
          <textarea id="message" class="materialize-textarea" ng-model="user.message"></textarea>
          <label for="message">Message</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="submit-button" ng-click="update(user)"><i class="material-icons left">check circle</i>Submit</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: where is `data.success` defined in the response? I can't find it

Comment: I changed that part to if(data)--I am not hitting that condition because I get the error part everytime. The post request is not successful.